# Main class typing in Python mixins

Tags: python, include, mixins, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class split into mixins:

```py
class MyObject(MyObjectFilesMixin, MyObjectProcessingMixin, ...):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = self.preprocess(value)
```

A mixin looks like this:

```py
class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls, filename):
        return ...
```

Now I'd like to add typing to the class and mixins:

```py
class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls, filename: str) -> MyObject:
        return ...


class MyObjectProcessingMixin:
    def preprocess(self: MyObject, value: bytes):
        return value  # logic is omitted

    def append(self: MyObject, other: MyObject):
        self.value += other.value
```

But it leads to cyclic links. Of course I can create some `MyObjectBase` (following dependency inversion principle), so that `MyObject` will also inherit this class, and mixins will use it as argument/return type, but this will lead to wrong types anyway. Is it possible to fix??

<sub>I miss so much header+source files from C++</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do the trick without protocols or other unnecessary code, [DRY!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) My solution is simple:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Type
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from my_object import MyObject
MO = Type('MyObject')


class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls: MO, filename: str) -> 'MyObject':
        # Now I'm able to access all the methods of MyObject by cls
        # with correct IDE support and MyPy checking
        return ...


class MyObjectProcessingMixin:
    def preprocess(self: 'MyObject', value: bytes):
        return value  # logic is omitted

    def append(self: 'MyObject', other: 'MyObject'):
        self.value += other.value
```

However, I get another warning, probably because MyPy doesn't expect a child to be used as a type in parent:

> Mypy: The erased type of self "Type[... MyObject]" is not a supertype of its class "Type[...MyObjectFilesMixin]"

But it's a little cost for the methods and types to be seen and understood correctly by IDE and MyPy!

Answer (score 3):

In the case of using mixin inheritance, [protocols and structural subtyping](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html?highlight=structural) and [TYPE_CHECKING](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#import-cycles) can help to successfully type classes by avoiding circular imports, it might look like this:

```
# my_object.py
from mixins import ProcessingMixin


class MyObject(ProcessingMixin):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = self.preprocess(value)

    def some_process(self, value) -> bytes:
        ...
```

```
# mixins.py
from typing import Protocol, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from my_object import MyObject

class ValueObjectProto(Protocol):
    """Protocol for value processing methods."""
    value: bytes

    def preprocess(self, value: bytes) -> bytes: ...
    def some_process(self, value) -> bytes: ...


class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls, filename: str) -> MyObject:
        return cast(Type[MyObject], cls)(1)

class ProcessingMixin:
    def preprocess(self: ValueObjectProto, value: bytes) -> bytes:
        value = self.some_process(value)
        return value

    def append(self: ValueObjectProto, other: ValueObjectProto) -> None:
        self.value += other.value
```

Comment: It's similar to my idea of `MyObjectBase` class, just more "magical" usage, but it also 1. requires specification of all the methods, and I have dozens of them in many files, and 2. the line `obj: MyObject = MyObject.load_from_file(...)` would be wrong cuz `load_from_file` will return some protocol object, which leads to ambiguity between my object class and such a protocol... Defining a protocol is a nice solution for building frameworks to deal with multiple separate classes, but here, with mentioned drawbacks, it looks like a crutch 

Comment: Not really, protocols are more flexible and allow you not to use inheritance in all cases. And the possibilities of `mypy` are limited, but hopefully, someone will suggest a more elegant solution.

Comment: I found a simpler solution, take a look 