# PEP-484 type hint for an invisibly-inherited property

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

How can I type-hint an `@property` which will come from an undeclared base class (as often occurs when using a mixin)?

E.g. to annotate "expected attributes" coming from the hidden inheritance hierarchy, I'm using:

```py
class SomeMixin:

  name: str
  logger: Logger

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

We always use `SomeMixin` in an inheritance hierarchy that proves `self.name` and `self.logger` attributes of type `str` and `Logger`.  So far, so good.

If the mixin is instead to be used where the `logger` is provided by another class is actually a property like:

```py
@property
def logger(self):
  return self.__logger
```

How can I type hint that in the mixin? I could keep using the existing attribute type hint as above, but then I get an "incompatible override" error while type checking, because `logger` is not in fact an attribute, for example:

```py
class Base:

  @property
  def logger(self) -> Logger:
    return Logger("foo")

class Derived(SomeMixin, Base):
  pass
```

The type checker will complain about `Dervied` have incompatible defintions of `logger`, e.g., in pyright:

```
Base classes for class "Derived" define variable "logger" in incompatible wayPylancereportIncompatibleVariableOverride
foo.py(17, 9): Base class "Base" provides type "property", which is overridden
foo.py(9, 5): Base class "SomeMixin" overrides with type "Logger"
```

I could use something like:

```py
class SomeMixin:

  name: str
  logger: property
```

... but then `logger` has type `Any` and I don't get the benefit of type checking on its value.

Comment: `logger: property` is wrong anyhow. It is implying that `instance.logger` is an instance of `property`

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what happens here: "but then I get an "incompatible override" error while type checking"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I added a specific example and the error message from pyright starting at `for example:`.

Comment: I'm providing a few duplicates below and pick one of then as a target - feel free to use any other. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283935/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-complex-mixin-classes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301988/main-class-typing-in-python-mixins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly add type-hints to Mixin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes)

Comment: Why is the mixin mentioning `logger` at all?

Comment: @chepner - the code implementing the mixin uses the logger property, to log.

Comment: @STerliakov - I used the current approach based on an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70907644, but it ran into this problem. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70907644/149138) would solve it, but it does not actually type check cleanly on the mixin itself as I described in the comment there. More generally though, the question is very different: as I'm asking specifically how to type hint _properties_ at the class level, while that question focuses on type hinting mixin attributes & methods.

Comment: Will the `@property` have a `setter`? This actually makes all the difference in the typing.

Comment: Right now, it seems like your mixin might *assume* that `self` has an instance attribute named `logger`, but that doesn't mean the class should be asserting its type.

Comment: @chepner - yes, it assumes that and yes it needs to type the property for type checking to work within the mixin. This is a typical typing approach for mixins attributes, and I would like to know if it can be extended to properties.

Comment: @dROOOze - it does not have a setter.

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of a quirk of python that `@property` and regular properties are essentially seen as distinct types. To fix your issue, you need to specify in `SomeMixin` that logger is a property:

```py
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, s:str) -> None:
      pass

class SomeMixin:
    name: str

    @property
    def logger(self) -> Logger:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Base:
    @property
    def logger(self) -> Logger:
        return Logger("foo")

class Derived(Base, SomeMixin):
    pass
```

I would also recommend using an abstract base class to ensure the property is overridden by the class that uses `SomeMixin`. This just ensures you can't initialise `SomeMixin` without combining it with another class to overwrite the method:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, s:str) -> None:
      pass

class SomeMixin(ABC):
    name: str

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def logger(self) -> Logger:
        ...

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Base:
    @property
    def logger(self) -> Logger:
        return Logger("foo")

class Derived(Base, SomeMixin):
    pass
```

*Side Note about inheritance: Notice I switched `Base` and `SomeMixin` in `Derived` - this is so that `Base` overrides `SomeMixin` and not the other way around.*