# Python Protocol incompatible warning

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to typehint, that my pure mixin (`MyMixin`) expects the super class to have the `get_context_data` method.

```
class HasViewProtocol(Protocol):
    kwargs: dict

    @abstractmethod
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        pass


class MyMixin(HasViewProtocol):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs) | {
            "extra_data": "bla"
        }
```

Here Pycharm's inspection issues:

```
type of 'get_context_data' is incompatible with 'HasViewProtocol`
```

- Are protocols the right aproach to annotate my expectation on the super class?
- Why is the `get_context_data` incompatible with the `HasViewProtocol`?

Comment: I'm not seeing this error in mypy playground (I see another one about `Call to abstract method "get_context_data" of "HasViewProtocol" with trivial body via super() is unsafe`). What versions are you using?

Comment: Protocols are the right way, but inheritance is (probably) not. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#mixin-classes, https://github.com/python/typing/issues/246, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301988/main-class-typing-in-python-mixins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, abstract method has no concrete implementation and any attempt to directly call such method is indicator of a bug. But in `MyMixin`'s `get_context_data()`  you are doing exactly that

```
class MyMixin(HasViewProtocol):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs) | {
           ....
```

attempting to call parent class' abstract method, so all linters I know would flag this as erroneous. Sure, I understand `MyMixin` is meant to be mixed into classes that already implement said `get_context_data()` but linter simply does not know that at this point. And it's not only PyCharms as other linters would complain too. I.e. `mypy` reports:

> error: Call to abstract method "get_context_data" of "HasViewProtocol" with trivial body via super() is unsafe [safe-super]

In fact `mypy` would do complain even you remove the decorator because of the `pass`-only implementation.

As for `Type of "get_context_data" is incompatible with "HasViewProtocol"` warning PyCharm spits, it's most likely related to how it sees the code, but IMHO  the message itself does not look right nor even much in context, so I'd suggest reporting that to JetBrains, using [PyCharm' bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Thanks - I do not quite understand, though. According to docs:

https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/protocol.html#protocol-members

protocol members can be abstract methods

Especially in the example here it is what they do:

https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/protocol.html#explicitly-declaring-implementation

I also don't understand the refactoring - it does exactly the same as the previous function but with more lines

Comment: I rewrote my answer former wasn't fully correct. Hope it makes more sense now :)

Comment: "abstract method has no concrete implementation". That's not entirely correct. You *can* provide an implementation if there is common behavior that all children can/should inherit, but the children are also expected to expand on by overriding the method.

Comment: Don't you really see no contradiction in "abstract" method having implementation? Python due to its nature as language allows to do multiple things odd way not possible in other languages and this not automatically "pro" for Python. Not even talking the "common behavior" (hope it's not that common though).